# Вопрос о getline()

Tags: c++, строки, getline

Написал этот код, но он не работает:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int a,b,c,d,e;
string s;

int main(){
    cin>>a;
    getline(cin,s);
    cin>>b;
    cout<<a<<" "<<s<<" "<<b;
    return 0;
}
```

Как я могу его исправить?
Например, если входные данные:

```
5
qa qaz qw
3
```

Программа должна написать:

```
5 qa qaz qw 3
```

Необходимо, чтоб эти  данные были сохранены.

Comment: Воспринимайте все значения как строки и ложите их в вектор. После просто выведете вектор

Comment: спасибо..........

Comment: как не догадался.

Comment: Зачем вы применили здесь `getline`?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете воспринимать все значения как строки(пользователю же все равно как данные внутри выглядят).

Алгоритм:

```
std::vector<std::string> inputs;

while(флаг ввода) {
    inputs.push_back(ввод);
}

for(std::string &str: inputs) {
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```